# Why do rays penetrate at all?

Tags: radiation

We know that the alpha, beta and gamma rays do penetrate through matter and all three have different penetrating abilities. What does it actually mean when it is said that a radiation of a particular particle is penetrating through matter? Does it mean that the particle moves through the matter undisturbed in its path?

Answer (score 1):

Exactly.

For example, think of an $\alpha$ particle, which is just a Helium nucleus.

Its size is on the order of $10^{-15}$ meters, and the distance between atoms in a solid is on the order of $10^{-10}$ meters, meaning there is plenty of room for the particle to move in and penetrate matter.

Comment: what about radiation? and how lead sheet absorbs X-ray radiation?

Comment: @BhavyaSharma it's the same with radiation, there's a chance that the photon will interact with an atom on the way through and be absorbed. Think of throwing a rock in the forest; the space between trees is much larger than the rock, but throw the rock far enough and you're still likely to hit a tree because there are so many of them.